# focus problem of two webviews in android development

Tags: android, webview

In two webviews we both have dom element like textarea. If we click on one textarea at this webview, and then click on the other textarea in the other webview, the focus problem comes out : they both focus and input method has problem

```
WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);
mWebView.setLayoutParams(webviewParams);
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/header.html");
mWebView.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS;

WebView mToolbar= new WebView(this);
mToolbar.setLayoutParams(toolbarParams);
mToolbar.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/footer.html");

mMainLayout.addView(mWebView);
mMainLayout.addView(mToolbar);
```